# In Java/Swing, why do we use classes for action listeners?

Tags: javascript, java, swing

This question is for my own curiosity.

In javaScript, we use addEventListener to assign methods to event callbacks, in Java, we use addActionListener, but we use entire classes that only have a single method in them. Why use a class with a single method instead of a simple callback function? That's basically what's happening anyway because our callback class only needs one method.

Comment: How else would you pass a method in Java?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are **completely** different languages.

Comment: a) Classes are pretty cheap, honestly.  b) Because Java didn't have any other way to pass around functions until recently (and even now it's often just generating the classes at runtime).

Comment: Thats the same reason Java8 introduce function as parameter.

Comment: @Pointy having worked with both, I know they're different, I'm just asking about the differences in how they both decide to handle similar functionality.

Comment: OK, but (until ES2015) JavaScript didn't *have* classes (and still doesn't really), and until JDK8 Java didn't have functions that exist outside of a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why use a class with a single method instead of a simple callback function?

Simply put, because that's not always the case.

Conceptually, the idea is the same, it's based on the [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), but rather than providing a function pointer, you're providing a class reference, but because classes can have multiple methods, you need a way for the event generator to know which method it should call.

Some event listeners are simple, like `ActionListener`, which only have a single method, but some are more complex, such as `AncestorListener`, `MouseListener`, `WindowListener`, which can respond to multiple different events.

The point is, the event listener interface defines the expected contract that the caller expects the recipient to conform to.  `interface`s are a key aspect of the Java language and how you use them is a very important concept to come to grips with.

You can use inner or anonymous class to make life easier and more recently you can also use lambda expressions, but essentially, they are still generating a class reference, it just makes it easier to write

Answer (score 1):

Basically because Java didn't have first-class functions until recent versions. So that was the only way to pass different behaviors around.

Comment: Event listeners can also be more complex than a single callback method, like `MouseListener` and `WindowListener`

Answer (score 1):

in Java8 you could use lambda expression

```
button.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Clicked"));
```

or

```
button.addActionListner(containingObject::instanceMethodName) ;
```